# I am getting '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType' for my python code

Tags: python

I have the following code, and when I try to run it I get the following error: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'. Here is the python code:

```
def quickSort (arr, left, right):

    #Checking the edge case 0 or 1 element subarray
    if left >= right:
        return arr
    
    #Setting our initial pivot to be the left, not random
    i = left

    #Swaping A[l] and A[i]
    to_swap = arr[left]
    arr[left] = arr[i]
    arr[i] = to_swap

    #We now define j to be our new pivot postion
    j = partition(arr, left, right)

    #Recurse on the first partition
    quickSort(arr, left, j)

    #Recurse on the second partition
    quickSort(arr, j + 1, right)

def partition(arr, left, right):
    p = arr[left]
    i = left + 1

    for j in range(left + 1, right):
        if arr[j] < p:

            #Swap A[j] and A[i]
            temp = arr[i]
            arr[i] = arr[j]
            arr[j] = temp

            #Restoring the invariant
            i = i + 1
        
        #Swap A[l] and A[i-1] which will allow us to place the pivot correctly
        temp = arr[left]
        arr[left] = arr[i-1]
        arr[i-1] = temp

        #Returning the final pivot postion 
        return i - 1
```

I am using the following code to run my program:

```
arrayTest1 = []
x1 = time.time_ns()
textFile1 = open('test1.txt')
data_set1 = textFile1.readlines()

for i in data_set1:
    sortArray1 = i.strip()
    inputText1 = int(sortArray1)
    arrayTest1.append(inputText1)

n1 = len(arrayTest1)
quickSort(arrayTest1, 0, n1)
print("\n\nArray for test1.txt: " + str(arrayTest1))

y1 = time.time_ns()
totalTime1 = y1 - x1
print('Total Time for first Array: ' + str(totalTime1))
```

And I test1.txt consists of simple array values 1-10.
Here is the traceback that shows the issue that I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 64, in <module>
    quickSort(arrayTest1, 0, n1)
  File "main.py", line 25, in quickSort
    quickSort(arr, j + 1, right)
  File "main.py", line 22, in quickSort
    quickSort(arr, left, j)
  File "main.py", line 22, in quickSort
    quickSort(arr, left, j)
  File "main.py", line 7, in quickSort
    if left >= right:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Please post the traceback and consider trimming down your code to something smaller that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `return i - 1` in `partition` looks strange. Why have a for loop that always returns on the first iteration? What if there is nothing to consume in the `for`? Then partition returns `None` (which could explain your error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only line that contains a `>=` is this one:

```
if left >= right:
```

The error says that you can't compare an `int` to a `NoneType` - which means that either `left` or `right` is an `int`, while the other is `None`.

I think @tdelaney found the root-cause:

> if there is nothing to consume in the for? Then partition returns None (which could explain your error).

If not, add a check/breakpoint at the beginning of `quicksort()` to check for `None` and dump the inputs when found:

```
if left is None or right is None:
  print("Invalid call to 'quicksort()' with inputs:\na=%s, l=%s, r=%s" % (arr, left, right))
  breakpoint()
```